# Can we show that $x^TA x \geq \alpha \:x^TA v_d$ with $\lambda_{\max}(A) = v_d^T A v_d$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a diagonal symmetric indefinite matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ whose maximal eigenvalue is $\lambda_d$ and whose associated eigenvector is $v_d$. Also, let $\beta>1$ and $0<\alpha<1$ where $\alpha$ is the solution of $\|x - \alpha v_d\|=\beta$. I want to prove

$$x^TA x \geq \alpha x^TA v_d,\tag{1}$$

for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and some $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Lets assume that,

$$\begin{align}x^TA x \geq \alpha x^TA v_d \Leftrightarrow &\sum_{ij}A_{ij} x_i x_j \geq \alpha A_{dd} x_d = \alpha \lambda_{d}  x_d \\   \Leftrightarrow & \lambda_{d} \geq \sum_{ij}A_{ij} x_i x_j = \alpha \lambda_{d}  x_d \\ \Leftrightarrow & 1 \leq \alpha x_d\end{align}, \tag{2}$$ where $\lambda_{d} \leq 0$ is used.

Next, given $\|x - \alpha v_d\|=\beta$ we have

$$\begin{align}\|x - \alpha v_d\|=\beta &\Leftrightarrow  \\
\|x\|^2 -2\alpha x_d + \alpha^2 = \beta^2 &\Leftrightarrow  \\ x_d^2 -2\alpha x_d + \alpha^2 \leq \|x\|^2 -2\alpha x_d + \alpha^2 = \beta^2 &\Leftrightarrow \\ (x_d -\alpha)^2 \leq \beta^2 &\Leftrightarrow \\ (\alpha x_d - \alpha)^2 \leq (x_d -\alpha)^2 \leq \beta^2 & \stackrel{\alpha <1}{\Leftrightarrow} \\  (1 - \alpha)^2 \leq \beta^2 & \stackrel{(2)}{\Leftrightarrow} \\ 0 \leq \alpha \leq \beta -1,  \tag{3}\end{align}$$ which for $\beta > 1$ holds as $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$.

Given $(3)$, can we state that by equivalence $(1)$ holds?

Moreover, In the proof, I have used $\lambda_{d} \leq 0$. However, in an indefinite matrix there may be at least one positive eigenvalue, i.e., $\lambda_{d} \geq 0$, which using $(2)$ implies $ 1 \geq \alpha x_d$. Can we state that

$$\begin{align}(\alpha x_d - \alpha)^2 \leq (x_d -\alpha)^2 \leq \beta^2 & \stackrel{\alpha <1}{\Leftrightarrow} \\  (1 - \alpha)^2 \leq \beta^2 & \stackrel{ 1 \geq \alpha x_d}{\Leftrightarrow} \\ 0 \leq \alpha \leq \beta -1,  \tag{4}\end{align}$$ where $ 1 \geq \alpha x_d$ is used to get a tighter lower bound?

Comment: What if $x=v_d/2$?

Comment: @thanks for the response. I am trying to prove that in the more general case.

Comment: No matter what $x$ you choose, can't you always choose an arbitrarily small (or negative) $\alpha$ for this inequality to hold?

Comment: Can we prove it for a more general case where $\alpha \in [\alpha_1, \alpha_2]$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand your notation here...

Comment: @Thoth I have looked at this problem and your inequality does not seem to hold. To finalize this, I would need some extra information. Is $\alpha$ real? Also, there may not be any $\alpha$ such as the norm equality holds. The term $\beta$ needs to be large enough for a solution to exist. Does $\alpha$ have fixed sign?

Comment: @KBS thanks for your interest. I  made some changes in my post and corrected some properties.

Comment: @Thoth I cannot see any answer to any of my questions. Does the inequality needs to hold for all the possible values for $\alpha$ that satisfy the equality constraint?

Comment: In the post I have included that $0<\alpha < 1$ and $\beta>1$. Also, I have added that $A$ is a real symmetric indefinite matrix if that helps.

Comment: @Thoth For some reason, the post did not refresh here. It is fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I have a counterexample. Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}  1&     0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

for which we have $$v_d=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and $\lambda= 1$. Note also that $v_d^Tv_d=1$.

Now pick $$x=\begin{bmatrix}0\\    \sqrt{\beta^2-\alpha^2}\end{bmatrix}$$ for any $\beta>1$ and $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

Now, with those values we have that $||x-\alpha v_d||=\beta$ together with $x^TAx=-(\beta^2-\alpha^2)<0$ and $\alpha v_d^TAx=0$, which shows that $x^TA x \ngeq \alpha x^TA v_d$.

Conversely, we may ask whether the reversed inequality $x^TA x \le \alpha x^TA v_d$ holds.

In this case, pick  $$x=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha+\beta\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ for any $\beta>1$ and $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Clearly, this $x$ verifies $||x-\alpha v_d||=\beta$.

Then, we have that $x^TAx=(\alpha+\beta)^2$ and $\alpha v^dAx=\alpha(\alpha+\beta)$. Since, $\beta>1$, we have that

$$x^TAx=(\alpha+\beta)^2>\alpha(\alpha+\beta)=\alpha v^dAx.$$ So the answer is no.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example. So can we say that the inequality $x^TA x \geq \alpha \:x^TA v_d$ works in the opposite direction for the same $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: @Thoth I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! Please let me ask, If $\alpha$ is real, i.e. takes negative and positive values and $\beta > 1$ is there any way to take $x^TA x \leq \alpha x^TA v_d$ for $A$ indefinite. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Thoth I guess that it will not work either. Just try to build counterexamples as I did. Note that in my counterexamples, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are left free. Try to see how you can select them to violate the inequality.

Comment: May I ask if there any possible combination of the domains of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in order to get $x^TA x \leq \alpha x^TA v_d$? For $A$ I know for sure that is not positive definite. Thus, $A$ is negative definite or more possibly for my problem $A$ is indefinite (i.e., non-convex). For $\beta$, in my problem I think it is bigger than one. Thanks again for you interest I hope to get a response.

Comment: My feeling is that there is no structure in what you want to do unless you get very restrictive. What I also think is that it is an XY problem. What is your actual and true problem you want to solve?

Comment: Thanks again for you interest. My question is a sub-part of an algorithm I am trying to construct. Thus, I found it difficult to describe the entire problem in a single post which conclude to this part. In any case your counter examples are very helpful to look for another direction.

Comment: Actually It is a trust-region optimizer I am trying to make for my research. If you wish to devote more time we could arrange to share more information with you privately and maybe cooperate on this, since I am stuck in this part.

Comment: @Thoth Sure I'll be happy to help if I can.

Comment: Thanks for your positive response. May I share my  e-mail?

Comment: Sure. I'll contact you then.

Comment: @Thoth Got it...